# Modal popup validation in MVC application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have `MareBook.cshtml` Partial view where I have done the validation to check if the textox `txtMare` is empty or not. If the textbox is not empty then display the textbox value into modal popup else do not display modal popup.

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Pedigrees", "Pedigrees", FormMethod.Post))
    {
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtMare)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.txtMare, "", new { @class = "error" })
      <button type="button" id="Producetable" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Maretable">Produce Page</button>

//Modal
<div id="Maretable" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
           ...
          <div class="modal-body">
          <h5>Producing table :<label id="msg"></label></h5>
          </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
           ....
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
         </div>              
        }
```

My script to get the value:

```
$(function () {
        $('#Producetable').click(function () {
          $('#msg').html($("#txtMare").val());
        });  
    });
```

Anyone please show me the way to do the validation. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean to check if the `txtMare` textbox has a value? If so you can just use `var value =  $("#txtMare").val(); if (value) { // display modal } })`. But if you have other validation attributes applied to that property you need to test the `.valid()` method of the validator

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Yes, I want to check if there is any value in textbox or not. Can you please provide simple sample for this. I am getting the value at this moment. please guide me.

Comment: The code in my previous comment will do that. If the textbox is empty, then `value` will be `null` if the code inside the `if` block will not execute

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Modal still showing even though `else` block is executing.                                                                                 
             `$(function () {
        $('#Producetable').click(function () {
            debugger;
            var value = $("#txtMare").val();
            if (value != "")
            {
                $('#msg').html($("#txtMare").val());
                $('#Maretable').modal('show');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#Maretable').modal('hide');
            }

        });  
    }); `

Comment: Did my code have `value != ""`??

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Sorry I removed that. Even though  it is executing `else` block, still modal shows up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163448/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-raj).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#Producetable").click(function() {
 var loInputText = $('#txtMare').val();
 if(loInputText != ""){
  $("#Maretable").show();
 }
});

function CloseModalPopup() {  
  $("#Maretable").hide();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


Add Your Input here: <input type="text" id="txtMare">
<br/><br/><button type="button" id="Producetable" class="btn btn-default">Produce Page</button>



<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="Maretable">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" onclick="CloseModalPopup();" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="CloseModalPopup();">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution is not properly working. When the modal pop up, I am not able to close it. Can you please check once. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Raj, you will be able to close modal popup now. I updated code and script, please recheck. Thanks :)